# Retrieving a library at build time in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

My project uses a dynamic library, and I wish to retrieve that library at build time in my iOS build, via a `Run Script` phase.

Unfortunately it appears Xcode takes a snapshot of your project before my `Run Script` phase is reached.

If the library was already present, the previous version is used, not the latest.

I could run the script separately before beginning the build, however I would like to minimise the number of steps required to include a new version of my library.

Is it possible to run a script before Xcode makes its copy of the project for building?

Yes I am aware this is an odd thing to do, thanks.

Comment: Is the project that builds this dependent dynamic library added to the *app* project and set as a dependency?